# how to print http request in logs oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

We are calling an external URL using `UTL_HTTP` methods and setting HTTP headers like `basic authentication`, `keep alive`, `content`, `soap action` so I need to print what I am setting as the header.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_http_request-'||l_http_request); -- not working
```

Below is the code

```
UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    if soap_action is not null then
    
        UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'SOAPAction', soap_action);
    end if;
    UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(request_clob));

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_http_request-'||l_http_request); ---how to print this
```

Answer (score 0):

Print them as you set them:

```sql
UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('l_http_request');

if soap_action is not null then
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'SOAPAction', soap_action);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' - SOAPAction=' || soap_action);
end if;

UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(request_clob));
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(' - Content-Length=' || LENGTH(request_clob));

DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
```

Comment: How to print final header which looks like below  , below from soap UI but i need to print in PLSQL code


Encoding: UTF-8
Headers: {SOAPAction=[setServiceInventoryDetails], content-length=[16549], Authorization: Basic VGVzdGVyOIRIc3Q=, host=[adoptu2luat.test.att.com], connection=[keep-alive, close], content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], user-agent=[Mozilla/4.0]},