# How to print final UTL_HTTP header in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to print final `UTL_HTTP` header in PL/SQL

Below(1) `UTL_HTTP` header from Soapui which we set from PL/SQL code by `UTL_HTTP` Methods I want print this PL/SQL code (2)

(1) Encoding: UTF-8
Headers: {SOAPAction=[setServiceInventoryDetails], content-length=[16549], Authorization: Basic VGVzdGVyOIRIc3Q=, host=[adoptu2luat.test.att.com], connection=[keep-alive, close], content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], user-agent=[Mozilla/4.0]},
env:Envelope
body
</env:Envelope>

2. How to print `DBMS_OUT.put_line` to know the final soap UTL Header?

```
l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request(url => p_url, method => 'POST', http_version => 'HTTP/1.1');
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Authorization', 'Basic ' || ws_unpw);  --cj208w
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Connection', 'close');
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Connection', 'keep-alive');
utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: What does "How to print final UTL_HTTP header in PL/SQL" mean? Please [edit] the question and include an English explanation (not code) of logic you want to implement and the expected output.

Comment: This appears to be related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76532888/how-to-print-http-request-in-logs-oracle). I cannot work out if this is a duplicate question or a follow-on question (possibly because I'm having difficulty working out what the aim of the question is).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use

```
BEGIN
    vlength := dbms_lob.getlength(request_body);
    owa_util.mime_header(ccontent_type => ''text/plain'',
                         bclose_header =>  true,
                         ccharset => ''ISO-8859-4'');
    HTP.p(''List from PRINT_CGI_ENV including <br /> terminator:'');
    HTP.p(''======================================================='');
    OWA_UTIL.print_cgi_env;
    htp.p(''Content-length: '' || vlength);
    HTP.p(''Request Body:'');
    HTP.p(''======================================================='');
     htp.p(request_body);
END;');
```

And then when this can via my REST API, I get something like this back -

[image]

[More info here where I talk about debugging your REST APIs in Oracle Database.](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/08/how-to-debug-your-rest-apis-in-oracle-rest-data-services/)